# How to find process bind to network interface

Tags: networking

I have two Hadoop processes (with web UI interface) running on a CentOS 5.3 machine inside a VirtualBox. I cannot access both interfaces from my host machine via port forwarding. Either first or second is not working and I cannot make both of them work concurrently.

Both processes are configured via guest hostname - master.
One web UI I can access via master:8088 or guest machine IP - 10.0.2.15:8088  but the second one I can access only via loacalhost:50070

I can make it work by modifying machine's `/etc/hosts` file:

```
127.0.0.1  localhost master
```

But obviously the second one stops working.

I have several questions:

1. Is there a way how to make both working?
2. Is it possible to find a network interface the process is bind to?
3. What is the relation between hostname and network interface?
4. Is it automatic that when I access on a guest machine master:8088 it gets translated to 12.0.2.15:8088? To me it seems that I have to have a host entry which maps those two together. Am I right? (I do not consider DHCP).

I tried to use `ifconfig` & `netstat` commands but that doesn't answer my questions so it would be great to clarify those.

Answer (score 0):

What you could do is to create a second network card for your linux machine so you can assign the processes each to a dedicated card. Then set both interfaces to bridged mode in virtualbox and assign them fixed LAN addresses in Linux.